# UNION CLAUSE USAGE

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I am working on a project on Oracle 11g to have an output for slow moving items. I have 2 different code to extract the data  which are 1. item that have sale less than 5 2. latest delivery date, latest delivery quantity. I am thinking of combining these two code into one using **UNION** can anyone please help me. I have tried, but error "query block has incorrect number of result columns" appear.

Answer (score 1):

if look at this part:

```
select  e.str_no,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD') del, e.goo_no AS goo_no,o.goo_na, 
sum(qty) totsale, (select qty from mkfstomi where goo_no = e.goo_no and str_no = e.str_no) sto

from mkfecrti e, mkfgoomi o , mkfgosmi s
where e.goo_no = o.goo_no and e.goo_no = s.goo_no and e.str_no = s.str_no
and e.str_no = 'TBS2' 
and e.deal_code = '00'  
and nvl(o.stop_pur,'N') <> 'Y' and nvl(s.stop_pur,'N') <> 'Y'--AND OSUNT_NA = 'UNIT'
and o.goo_status <> '9' 
and e.tdate between date '2019-10-01' and date '2019-10-31'
having sum(qty) < 5
group by e.str_no, e.goo_no,o.goo_na ,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD')

union all

SELECT distinct m.str_no,m.del,  m.goo_no AS Item_Code , m.goo_na, 0 totsale, 0 sto,d2.qty AS Latest_delivery_quantity ,m.max_date AS Latest_delivery

FROM (SELECT j.str_no, k.goo_no,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD') del, MAX(k.kdate) AS max_date, o.goo_na
FROM MKFTTOTI k, MKFTTO01 h, mkfgoomi o, mkfstrmi j
where k.seq_no=h.seq_no
and k.goo_no=o.goo_no
and k.str_no=j.str_no
and h.tto_code='2F'
and k.qty > 0
and j.str_no='TBS2'
and j.close_date is NULL
and nvl(o.stop_pur,'N') <> 'Y'
GROUP BY k.goo_no,o.goo_na, j.str_no,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD')) m
JOIN MKFTTOTI d2 ON d2.goo_no = m.goo_no AND d2.kdate = m.max_date and d2.qty > 0
```

The first portion is missing d2.qty AS Latest_delivery_quantity ,m.max_date AS Latest_delivery. That means you are doing an union where the two aprt dont have the same count of columns.

Try this below, it should work:

```
select str_no, del, item_code, goo_na, sum(totsale), sum(sto),  sum(Latest_delivery_quantity), Latest_delivery
from 
(select  e.str_no,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD') del, e.goo_no AS goo_no,o.goo_na, 
sum(qty) totsale, (select qty from mkfstomi where goo_no = e.goo_no and str_no = e.str_no) sto, null as Latest_delivery_quantity ,null AS Latest_delivery
from mkfecrti e, mkfgoomi o , mkfgosmi s
where e.goo_no = o.goo_no and e.goo_no = s.goo_no and e.str_no = s.str_no
and e.str_no = 'TBS2' 
and e.deal_code = '00'  
and nvl(o.stop_pur,'N') <> 'Y' and nvl(s.stop_pur,'N') <> 'Y'--AND OSUNT_NA = 'UNIT'
and o.goo_status <> '9' 
and e.tdate between date '2019-10-01' and date '2019-10-31'
having sum(qty) < 5
group by e.str_no, e.goo_no,o.goo_na ,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD')
union all
SELECT distinct m.str_no,m.del,  m.goo_no AS Item_Code , m.goo_na, 0 totsale, 0 sto,d2.qty AS Latest_delivery_quantity ,m.max_date AS Latest_delivery
FROM (SELECT j.str_no, k.goo_no,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD') del, MAX(k.kdate) AS max_date, o.goo_na
FROM MKFTTOTI k, MKFTTO01 h, mkfgoomi o, mkfstrmi j
where k.seq_no=h.seq_no
and k.goo_no=o.goo_no
and k.str_no=j.str_no
and h.tto_code='2F'
and k.qty > 0
and j.str_no='TBS2'
and j.close_date is NULL
and nvl(o.stop_pur,'N') <> 'Y'
GROUP BY k.goo_no,o.goo_na, j.str_no,decode(o.ord_send,0,'DC',3,'DD')) m
JOIN MKFTTOTI d2 ON d2.goo_no = m.goo_no AND d2.kdate = m.max_date and d2.qty > 0
)
group by str_no, del,item_code, goo_na
;
```

Comment: it worked, but the output appear twice for the same item_code. the first line the latest_delivery_quantity and latest_delivery is null while the second line of the same item code the totsal and sto null. how to make it appear one on the same line

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both ‘tables’ you are unioning have the same number of columns.

Comment: i tried to do that, but I dont know how to use it on date,

Comment: @newbeginnner how to use what on date?

Comment: Maybe you just need to join those last columns on then instead of a union. Like a vlookup basically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You just get rid of the all in union all.
Union all keeps the duplicates.

Hope it helps